# c# UI Automation label

Tags: c#, ui-automation

I am using Microsoft's UI Automation library for quite a while now, and I have been able to manipulate textboxes and buttons. However, I have problems with some of the controls.

I have a program that I want to automate, which have a picture box and a link label that functions like a button click. This means that if I clicked on the picture box or the link label, I will trigger an event, and be directed to another page.

I have tried using the invoke method, which buttons have, but was unsuccessful. Is there any other way to trigger the click event or something similar for a picture box or link label?

Thanks in advance.

Microsoft's UI Automation library: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms747327.aspx

Answer (score 1):

<< I have a program that I want to automate, which have a picture box and a link label that functions like a button click >> - this sounds like it is a picture or label control that is just handing mouse down events, but not otherwise letting the system know that it behaves like a button. Your best bet in cases like these is to use UIAutomation to get the bounding rectangle, and then use SendInput to move the mouse there and perform a click yourself.

UIAutomation only knows how to deal with standard buttons. Anything that's basically a custom button - eg. label that handles mouse down - would need to add support for some extra interfaces in order to tell UIAutomation that it can be clicked and to provide support for the Click method itself.

Answer (score 0):

Buttons have a `PerformClick()` method.

Comment: The question asks for a solution on a label, not a button.

Comment: Maybe one of us misunderstood the question: "*Is there any other way to trigger the click event...*?" My answer points out a method on a button which may be called programmatically.

Comment: the question citation goes on with "...  *for a picture box or link label*" ? A method available for buttons therefore does not help. As far as I understand the question and the answer :) By the way I ended up in this post because I was searching for a solution for a label...

Answer (score 0):

It's possible to change the behavior of Winforms controls with regard to UI Automation. If you want a PictureBox to be seen as a button by UI Automation, and therefore be clickable using UI Automation tools, you can derive from PictureBox and override Automation/Accessible methods, something like this:

Before:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        var pb = new PictureBox();
        pb.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
        pb.Click += (s, e) => MessageBox.Show("hello world");
        Controls.Add(pb);
    }
}
```

This is how Inspect (from the SDK tools) sees it, as a "pane", with no specific action:

[image]

After:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        var pb = new ButtonPictureBox();
        pb.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
        pb.Click += (s, e) => MessageBox.Show("hello world");
        Controls.Add(pb);
    }
}

public class ButtonPictureBox : PictureBox
{
    protected override AccessibleObject CreateAccessibilityInstance() => new Accessible(this);

    private class Accessible : ButtonBase.ButtonBaseAccessibleObject
    {
        public Accessible(ButtonPictureBox control)
            : base(control)
        {
        }

        public new ButtonPictureBox Owner => (ButtonPictureBox)base.Owner;
        public override AccessibleRole Role => AccessibleRole.PushButton;
        public override AccessibleStates State => AccessibleStates.Default;
        public override void DoDefaultAction() => Owner.OnClick(EventArgs.Empty);
    }
}
```

Now, Inspect sees it as a "button" and the Invoke Pattern is available, so if you Invoke it, the Click method will be raised:

[image]